# Is there a way to assign a templated type to a defined class structure?

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, generics, containers

I am trying to create a simple binary tree capable of holding data of multiple types. The binary tree will be hard coded with data (compile time could work for this). Here is my code:

```cpp
class BTree {
  template <typename T>
  struct Node {
    Node* left_ = nullptr;
    Node* right_ = nullptr;

    T data_;

    explicit Node(T value) : data_(value) {}
  };

  Node<int>* root_ = nullptr;

public:
  BTree() {
    root_ = new Node<int>(2);

    auto ptr = root_;
    ptr->left_ = new Node<const char*>("SomeString");
  }
};
```

I get the error message "Cannot assign to type Node<int>* from Node<const char*>*".

Now, I fully understand what the error message is saying and I know there is no way to convert a `char*` into an `int`, but is there a way to have my `left_` and `right_` pointer members to point at a templated type?

For this project, I cannot include any third-party libraries.

I tried changing them to `Node<T>*` but it still doesn't work because when the initial `root_` node is created, it is created with an `int` type. I also tried making a custom = operator:

```cpp
Node<T>& operator=(const Node<const char*>* ptr) {
  left_ = nullptr;
  right_ = nullptr;

  data_ = *ptr->data_;

  return this;
}
```

This also does not work and at this point I'm a little bit out of my scope.

Comment: Are you trying to mix data types in a single tree?  What kind of operations do you expect to support on this mixed-type tree?  All the usual insertion and lookup operations rely on being able to compare two values, which is going to be a big problem if the values aren't the same type.

Comment: @BenVoigt A binary tree is not necessarily a binary search tree (it's not necessarily sorted).

Comment: @Nelfeal: Good point, I was misled by the class name because `B-Tree` is shorthand for binary search tree, but the question indeed doesn't say it is a search tree.  Still, even walking the data structure is going to be hard if nothing is known about the data types.

Comment: @BenVoigt Apologies for not mentioning that this will indeed be a search tree. However, the tree itself will be hardcoded and the values will be known. The way I plan on searching will be checking to see if the `left_` and `right_` nodes are `nullptr`, thus my search function will only ever be comparing `int` and returning a string.

Comment: Offtopic: A strange requirement. Binary tree implies some order. How to introduce order of values of different types? IMO you should specify what problem this code suppose to solve. Best specification is in form of tests which should pass. Now I suspect [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @BenVoigt In fact B-tree is not a binary tree, it is [something altogether different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree).

Comment: "my search function will only ever be comparing int and returning a  string" This makes very little sense.

Comment: Are you looking for [std::any](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)?

Comment: @n.m.: Even your link describes a B-tree as a binary search tree...

Comment: @n.m.: You skipped over the "checking to see if the left_ and right_ nodes are nullptr" part -- apparently all leaf nodes contain strings and all non-leaf nodes contain `int`.

Comment: This is starting to sound like a `std::map<int, string_type>` (which is actually implemented as a red-black tree)

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't think "Not to be confused with" has this meaning.

Comment: @n.m. "Not to be confused with" doesn't mention "binary search tree", only "binary tree".  But the next paragraph does relate it to "binary search tree", twice.

Comment: @BenVoigt "You skipped over the ---" No, I just don't take things at their face value.

Comment: @BenVoigt It is the other way around. It is a search tree, but not a binary tree (and not a binary search tree). It is related to binary search trees, but "related" is not "is".

Comment: @n.m. Probably wikipedia is worded wrong.  But "T is a generalization of R" states a subtype relationship.  And then in the next sentence, still in the first paragraph, it refers to "other binary search trees", which implies a subtype relationship in the other direction.

Comment: @BenVoigt This discussion makes no sense and is wildly off topic.

Comment: I think a B-Tree with 2 potential child (as OP's case) is essentially a balanced binary search 
 tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the immediate problem of being able to build the tree of pointers by using inheritance.

```
struct NodeBase
{
    NodeBase* left = nullptr;
    NodeBase* right = nullptr;
};

template <typename T>
struct Node : NodeBase
{
    T data;
    explicit Node(T value) : data(value) {}
};

NodeBase* root = nullptr;
```

Now you can build the tree and walk through it.  But you can't do anything with the values in each node unless you have external knowledge of the type of each one.

Comment: I'm afraid this bit of knowledge, although technically correct, is useless to OP.

Comment: @n.m.: From the comments he apparently does have external knowledge of the type -- leaf nodes (as detected by `left` and `right` being null pointers) contain a different type from internal nodes.

Comment: Search trees don't work this way.

Comment: While this solution would definitely help solve my problem, I have decided on a different approach entirely, where I used `enum` constants assigned to integers that don't exist within my table. The search returns a simple string depending on the final value. You were correct in assuming this is actually a red-black tree with only the leaves containing strings. Unfortunately, your solution is no longer applicable to the current state of my project, but I appreciate the help nonetheless!

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to create a simple binary tree capable of holding data of multiple types.

A single binary search tree normally holds data of one single type. Different unrelated trees may hold data of different types, but each tree should hold one and only one type.

In C++ this is normally achieved by templatizing the type of the tree (as opposed to just the type of the node).

```
template <typename T>
class BinarySearchTree {
   struct Node {            // not a template on its own
      T data;
      Node* left;
      Node* right;
   };
   Node* root;
   // the rest of the tree class
};
```

You should take into account that `BinarySearchTree<const char*>` won't do what you want. Use `BinarySearchTree<std::string>` or roll your own simplified `string` class.

At a later stage you may also want to parameterise the tree with additional template parameters, such as the comparator and the allocator.

Comment: Footnote: this is my understanding of what you might actually need, as opposed to what you are saying you need. I could be totally wrong about it. If you think I am, please provide your requirements in your domain language. For example, something like "I am writing a system capable of searching people by their name, address, and phone number". Do not use tech jargon like "binary search tree" when stating the requirements, but uf course use it when describing your implementation.

Comment: Whether there's an underlying X-Y problem, "create a binary search tree capable of holding data of multiple types" is a reasonable and useful goal (maybe not to OP if he has an X-Y problem, but certainly to some people like authors of scripting language interpreters).  Don't dismiss it out of hand.

Comment: "is a reasonable and useful goal" No it is not.